# Angular2: “Navigating” to an overlay

Tags: angular

In the Angular2.0b6 app I’m working on (my first contact with Angular2), up to now I only used “regular” hyperlink navigation based on `[routerLink]`.

But now, I would like to “navigate” to an overlay (some element floating above the current page) instead. In the end, the overlay should include a model-based form for editing one of the items displayed on the page underneath the overlay. It would be easy for me to do it with jQuery or plain JS, but I would like to do it “the Angular way”.

Naturally, the element which opens the overlay must have an `(click)` “attribute” which triggers an event handler. But what to do in the event handler? From my understanding, I would need to add a component to the page, with the component being responsible for handling the form submission. But how do I get that component on screen?

Answer (score 2):

In this [folder](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material/src/components/dialog) of Angular 2 Material (its on early stages), there is an example of how to do this. You can run the app as well to see it in action.

The bulk of the solution is to create a custom Dialog component, and when you want to open the dialog only then load it into the page using `DynamicComponentLoader`.

This way you will not have to pre-render the dialog and keep it hidden on the page until its displayed, reducing the overall html size.

Comment: DynamicComponentLoader! That was it! I read about it, but I forgot the name … Will look into it. Thanks.